# run hector_slam with LaserScan topic only

Tags: slam, navigation, laser, hector, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to get work with hector_slam using SICK Laser. I want to map a room with SICK laser only. I will carry my notebook with the SICK Laser.

What I have tried :

1. Record the /scan topic with rosbag record.
2. Play it again with rosbag play <filename.bag> --clock
3. Launch this file :

   ```
    <node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">

        <param name="base_frame" value="base_link"/>
        <param name="odom_frame" value="base_link"/>
        <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
        <param name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" value="25"/>

        <!-- Map size / start point -->
        <param name="map_resolution" value="0.050"/>
        <param name="map_size" value="2048"/>
        <param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
        <param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
        <param name="map_multi_res_levels" value="2" />
    </node>

    <include file="$(find hector_geotiff)/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch"> </include>

    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_nav_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 100"/>
   ```

But, I got this error :

```
[ INFO] [1372396116.210768520, 1372324835.547738080]: lookupTransform base_link to laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
[ERROR] [1372396116.373757080, 1372324835.710765040]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to /base_link failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (3): Frame /laser exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
```

I am afraid that my launch file is wrong. Do anyone has .launch for hector_slam that can be use for handheld mapping only. Thank you :)

Update :

Here,it is my result from rosrun tf view_frames :

> https_://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32191086/Public%20Media/Selection_001.png

remove the _ for link

And my .bag file :

> https_://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32191086/Public%20Media/pioneer_laser_1.bag

Sorry my karma isn't enough to post the picture & link.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66176/run-hector_slam-with-laserscan-topic-only/) by [pseudobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/5263/pseudobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2013-06-27**:
please, post the output of the command "rosrun tf view_frames", so we can see how your frames are configured.

**Comment by [pseudobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/5263/pseudobot/) on 2013-06-27**:
Here it is :
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32191086/Public%20Media/Selection_001.png

**Comment by [goetz.marc](https://answers.ros.org/users/4958/goetz.marc/) on 2013-06-27**:
try putting   into your launch file

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2013-06-28**:
when you start hector_slam it prints a bunch of stuff in the initialization phase, can you also post that, please? If your bag file is not too big I can try to process it here and tell you what you are missing.

**Comment by [pseudobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/5263/pseudobot/) on 2013-06-28**:
@goetz.marc I have try that but still error :(

@Procopio : here it is my bag file, it contains LaserScan /scan topic only : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32191086/Public%20Media/pioneer_laser_1.bag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, it is actually quite simple, just add this line to your launch file:

```
<param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />
```

and play your bag file with the **--clock** argument:

```
rosbag play pioneer_laser_1.bag --clock
```

this modifications will make the clock of your bag file to be used, instead of the current system time. Without them, you would have a large difference in time between the time you got your laser scans and the current time of your static transformation. Then the system would disregard your static transform because your scans were too old.

If you had recorded the static transformation together with the scan in the bag file, you would probably have it working in the first try.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2013-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pseudobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/5263/pseudobot/) on 2013-06-28**:
Thanks, I can play that now & the map coming in the rviz. Btw, if I am using with realtime scanner, I must set that param value to "false" ?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2013-06-29**:
I'm not sure, but I think it would work even if you left it as "true".